# Networking in 2003 SP2 VM running under 2012 Standard Hyper-V, adapter failing

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012

We had a 2003 SP2 Web/SQL Server VM running on a hosts hardware. The hosting company became unresponsive so we decided to move the VM. So far I have done the following:

- I used disk2vhd to create a vhd of the running VM.
- I downloaded the vhd to my local computer and started it using Virtual PC.I then ran sysprep.
- I ordered a Windows 2012 Standard dedicated server with one dedicated IP address.
- I added the Hyper-V role, and set up an External switch under the Virtual Switch Manager.
- I copied the VHD to the server and created a new VM, which booted fine.
- I installed the integration services.

Now, when I start and connect to the VM I have a warning on the network adapter. The Status shows "...the network did not assign an network address to the computer"

When I look at Details...

```
Physical Address (a mac address)
IP Address 169.254.107.25
Subnet Mask 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway (blank)
DNS Server (blank)
WINS Server (blank)
```

Dammit Jim, I'm a developer, not a server admin! Anyway, I'm obviously missing something in the configuration but most of what I've found on the web just says to set up the External switch and you're good which isn't the case here.

I can buy an additional IP if it helps. Ultimately we'll be running SQL and IIS off the 2003 VM, so I need to make sure I have everything set up so I can point the domain name to the VM and connect to the VM via RDP and SSMS. Maybe there's some forwarding or something that I have to configure once I get the network adapter sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on an OVH dedicated server (KS level). The solution was to order one of the Failover IP addresses via the OVH account portal and use that for the VM in the following way:

- Order the failover IP
- Add a Virtual Mac address via the OVH portal
- In Hyper-V Manager, edit the VM to set the Mac address of the network adapter to the generated one
- In the VM, set the IP, gateway, subnet similar to those in the host but using the new IP, but the new IP with .254 as the final numbers for the gateway, and 255.255.255.0 for the subnet
- Using regedit, find the new IP and change the subnet to 255.255.255.255

That got me connected. Once connected I found that I needed to open ports in both the host and in the VM to get them to work, like for FTP, SQL manager, RDP.

Answer (score 0):

The VM needs an IP address (separate from the Hyper-v host). If it's on a network without DHCP you need to figure out which IP address to use. Your question doesnt say much about the networking details, but if it's a hosted environment I'm guessing you need to buy an additional IP and assign this to the vm.